# Accessing lazy loaded entity object in Junit

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, persistence

I am trying to test a entity value in Junit, the entity has many-to-many relation with lazy fetch type.

When I try to expand this in Junit I am getting the following error.  ***Please hightlight if my understanding is wrong, all I need is to have the session opened in Junit and load this object.***

**SEVERE: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.stock.model.Stock.locations, no session or session was closed**
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.stock.model.Stock.locations, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:249)
    at com.example.common.StockManytoManyTest.testGetStock(StockManytoManyTest.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotate your integration test class or method with `@Transactional`. See also: [10.3.5.4 Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks !

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz is there a way to achieve this without `@Transactional`? Check out this haha: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/11/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html

Answer (score 1):

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class TestAnything{
   ...
}
```